# I created a mobile responsive web site. its all working fine but it can't be scrolled smoothly

Tags: html, css

I used following code to smooth scrolling.

```
html,body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    overflow-x:hidden;  
    scroll-behavior:smooth;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the link so i got what exactly the problem is?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about your problem, what type of issue are you having? Is the scroll working on desktop but not mobile? You are aware that scroll-behavior doesn't work for mouse scroll, only scrolling between clicked links to other parts of the same page, correct?

Comment: now its ok . it seems to work fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The scroll-behavior property specifies whether to smoothly animate the scroll position, instead of a straight jump, when the user clicks on a link within a scrollable box.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_scroll-behavior.asp) is how to use smooth scroll

Comment: I'm happy I was of help to you